# I am trying to get device but it gives me null

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to get device token but it gives me null here is my code :

```dart
String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
        print (token);
```

Comment: Did you initialise Firebase correctly? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
   String? token = value;
});
```

Comment: Failed to get FIS auth token, I got this error

Comment: Then it means your app could not communicate with Firebase server, try to initialise Firebase correctly.

Comment: This async style of the same operation as author wrote it can't work differently @Abdullah

Comment: I checked it initialised correctly